# looping a command without waiting for the first run

Tags: bash, shell

I want a better way to do this, mostly for command line use:

```
while sleep 60; do 
  mysql -e 'show processlist'; 
done
```

This is better than:

```
while mysql -e 'show processlist'; do
  sleep 60;
done
```

... because if I type a `ctrl-c`, it stops.  However, the first version waits for a minute before first output.

I know about `watch`.  Often good, but not for all circumstances.  I'm looking for a simple output to stdout, not curses.  It'd be nice if `watch` had a `--stdout` option.

Simplicity is key here.  I don't care about handling errors in the mysql statement.  It can report its own errors to stdout.

Comment: And in second version it doesn't stop after `Ctrl-C`?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you're trying to do. Your two commands are not equivalent (they will react differently if the `mysql` command return an error for example).

Comment: @jimmij it only stops if the ctrl-c causes the command in the while statement to fail.  if that's the statement that runs only briefly, then the ctrl-c will probably land in the body of the loop, which doesn't stop the loop.

Comment: @terdon they are similar if nothing fails.  Different on failure, which is most likely when ctrl-c is pressed, which is kinda the point.  sure there's no error checking for the mysql statement, but brevity is the key as this is for command line use.

Comment: Yes, but I am still not sure what you want to do. It _looks_ like you are trying to run the mysql command once a minute for ever. You also seem to have some requirements about how to stop it. Please [edit] and state what you need clearly. That will help both those who want to answer and anyone else who might search for similar functionality.

Comment: Tell us in what circumstances you're running this snippet and exactly how you're killing it. Normally Ctrl+C would interrupt any of the possibilities since the signal is sent to the whole foreground process group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does kill the whole loop under normal circumstances. The signal is sent to the whole foreground process group.

You may be looking for

```
while mysql -e 'show processlist' && sleep 60; do :; done
```

which exits as soon as either `mysql` or `sleep` fails.

Answer (score 1):

This one might work for you:

```
trap "pkill -TERM -P $$" SIGINT

while [ 1 ]; do
   mysql -e 'show processlist'
   sleep 60
done
```

Comment: `while true;` or `while :;` are valid alternatives

Comment: Doesn't help.  ctrl-c doesn't kill the loop.  mysql is quite capable of issuing its own error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for your example...

```
n=; while sleep "$((n&(n=60)))"
do   mysql...
done
```

...will do it. On the first go it will `sleep 0` and all of the rest will `sleep 60`. Still, I think probably there is a better way to reach your end goal than this.

If you did use something like this you'd probably want to do it in a function:

```
every_minute() ( n=
    while sleep "$((n&(n=60)))"
    do "$@"; done)
```

...or in a single line...

```
every_minute() (n=; while sleep "$((n&(n=60)))"; do "$@"; done)
```

If you put something like that in your shell's rc file you could just do...

```
every_minute mysql "$whatever" "$args" "$you" "$use"
```

...or you could just type out the single-line version at any prompt and continue to use it until you close the shell.

Comment: Kinda funky.  I'm hoping there's something easier to remember correctly and to type though.

Comment: @mc0e You plan to type this more often than once? You just need to put this in a function, man.

Comment: functions and aliases are cool, but I work across dozens of heterogeneous servers, many of which are not mine, and often I'm landing in an unfamiliar server.  I want techniques I can use fast without installing stuff.  I do have various things wrapped up in function statements I can paste in when needed, but if I don't need that then it's better.

Comment: @mc0e - you really don't have to install a function. Just type that `every_minute()` definition at the prompt once and it's good for the life of the shell - or until you `unset -f` it.